# Yii creating a Amazon Product API class

Tags: rest, yii, model, amazon-product-api

I am trying to design my Class Diagram. But I get stuck on this one.

I have already created all database corresponding models. But this time I need to create a model for Amazon API with no corresponding database for it.

When creating a model for the database I use CActiveRecord. But for this one I dont know which one I can extend from.
[Look at this CWebService:](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebService)

This is for SOAP, but the Amazon Product API uses REST.

So the question is, when creating a model to call a REST API which class I need to extend from?

EDIT: I do NOT want to create a REST API. I want to CALL a REST API and write a class for that.

Comment: have you looked at [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/)?

Comment: I do NOT want to create a REST API. I want to CALL a REST API and write a class for that. Something different :)

Comment: alright, i think you can just extend from [CModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel), not sure though

Comment: there's an [extension also](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activeresource) have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have looked at it. But that is not the solution, because of they lack functionality I need to call the API. (Edit: I think.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ActiveResource extension for Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activeresource). Also indicated to you by bool.dev.

Now for instance if you want to get details about certain product you `GET` 
`http://api.am.com/prodcut //(just a dummy url for reference)`

The models you need to create will need to satisfy/handle the data being returned to you. 
If you are displaying the returned data in a Form extend from `CFormModel`. if you are not showing it in a Form extend from `CModel` to create a data model.

For example if you are just showing the data in a table view you can create a model for product like so:
`class product extends CModel`

Hope this helps unless I misunderstood your problem

(I was gonna post this as a comment but thought it was too long for the comment).